# How can you simplify this expression for amount of triangles?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I was given a question as a challenge were I was supposed to find a formula to find how many triangles there are when you draw $n$ and $m$ amount of lines from points $N$ and $M$ to the opposite sides.

Open this link for illustration
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_DugfV8U0fjdFRfX0prTXZLd2M

If you've noticed there is a pattern in the intersections of the two lines as if you continue along your $n$th line you find that the sum of the triangles formed at the intersections iterate $m+1$ amount of times. Therefore you can generalize this and express it like this:

$$\sum_{y=1}^{n+1} \sum_{x=y}^{m+y} x$$

My problem is that i cant find a way to simplify the outer sum of this expression which is $\sum_{y=1}^{n+1} \frac{m^2 + 2ym + 2y + m}{2}$. I am very new to series but tried manipulating these expressions to express them in terms of $n$ and $m$ only to get a formula which fails consistently. I am not testing if they work by eye but i am using a program i wrote to check if its true in case i make any mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You want [Faulhaber's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).  Your inner sum is the $p=1$ case.  You can deal with the fact that the lower index is not $1$ by saying $$\sum_{x=y}^{m+y} x=\sum_{x=1}^{m+y} x-\sum_{x=1}^{y-1} x=\frac 12(m+y+1)(m+y)-\frac 12y(y-1)$$.  Now plug this into the outer sum.

Comment: Sorry that i didn't say this but it is my outer sum i am having trouble with, I edited my post to fix it.

Comment: In your outer sum, the $m$'s are constants, so you are only summing constants times $1$, which sums to $n+1$ and constants times $y$, which sums to $\frac 12(y+1)(y+2)$